# php Imagick color overlay

Tags: php, imagick

Okay i think i maybe have misundertode the function of colorizeImage in the Imagick.
Im trying to add 70% black color to a image. But the code only works if its 1 and then its just a black image.

but from the manual i can't seem to find the problem.
http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.colorizeimage.php

```
$backdropInFile = JPATH_BASE . '/images/movies/'.$_POST["movieid"].'/backdrop'.$movie['backdrop_path'];
$backdropOutFile = JPATH_BASE . '/images/movies/'.$_POST["movieid"].'/backdrop/'.$_POST["movieid"].'_backdrop.jpg';
$backdropimage = new Imagick($backdropInFile);
$backdropimage->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$backdropimage->setImageCompressionQuality(60);
$backdropimage->colorizeImage('#000',0.9);
$backdropimage->thumbnailImage(1700, null);
$backdropimage->writeImage($backdropOutFile);
```

does some one know what is wrong, or have another way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay i found a solution to the problem, by doing it a another way.
Here the code

```
$backdropInFile = JPATH_BASE . '/images/movies/'.$_POST["movieid"].'/backdrop'.$movie['backdrop_path'];
$backdropOutFile = JPATH_BASE . '/images/movies/'.$_POST["movieid"].'/backdrop/'.$_POST["movieid"].'_backdrop.jpg';
$backdropimage = new Imagick();
$backdropimage->setBackgroundColor('black');
$backdropimage->readimage($backdropInFile);
$backdropimage->setImageOpacity(0.25);
$backdropimage->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$backdropimage->setImageCompressionQuality(60);
$backdropimage->thumbnailImage(1700, null);
$backdropimage = $backdropimage->flattenImages();
$backdropimage->writeImage($backdropOutFile);
```

I stead of using colorize, i set the background color to be black before openning the file. Then i set the image to be 25% transparent. And then i flatten the image and save.

Answer (score 0):

The colorize works weirdly. It's actually a vector based operation I think. It sounds like you just want to adjust the color, which you can do more easily by drawing a coloured rectangle over the image.

```
function colorizeImagick(Imagick $imagick, $color, $alpha = 1) {
    $draw = new ImagickDraw();

    $draw->setFillColor($color);

    if (is_float($alpha)) {
        $draw->setFillAlpha($alpha);
    }

    $width = $imagick->getImageWidth();
    $height = $imagick->getImageWidth();

    $draw->rectangle(0, 0, $width, $height);

    $imagick->drawImage($draw);
}
```